# ReactJS: function post axios error: is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a form, and I'm trying to make a post.

In the form when it is submitted I call the saveEntity function:

```
import { createEntity } from './realmUser-reducer'

export interface IRealmUserUpdateProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }> { }

export const RealmUserUpdate = (props: IRealmUserUpdateProps) => {
interface LocationState {
    userId: number | string
}
const location = useLocation<LocationState>()

  const saveEntity = (event, errors, values) => {
     if (errors.length === 0) {
       const entity = {
         realm: {id: values.realm},
         user: {userId: location.state}
        }
       props.createEntity(entity)  // this error:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.createEntity is not a function
    }
   }


return(//.....)


const mapStateToProps = (storeState: IRootState) => (
    {
    });

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    createEntity
}


type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RealmUserUpdate);
```

in my reducer:

```
export const createEntity: ICrudPutAction<IRealmUser> = entity => async dispatch => {
    const result = await dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_REALMUSER,
        payload: axios.post(apiUrl, cleanEntity(entity)),
    });
    return result;
};
```

the model that I created:

```
export interface IRealmUser {
    id?: string | number | null;
    user?: {
        perCod?: any
    }
    realm?: {
        id?: number | string | null
    }
}

export const defaultValue: Readonly<IRealmUser> = {};
```

So my problem is that when I'm trying to do the post I receive an error:

> the error:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.createEntity is
> not a function

about the `props.createEntity(entity)`

EDIT1:

Adding console.log(props)

```
history: {
    "length": 50,
    "action": "PUSH",
    "location": {
        "pathname": "/realmUser/new",
        "state": 156001,
        "search": "",
        "hash": "",
        "key": "2dwfy5"
    }
}
location:{
    "pathname": "/realmUser/new",
    "state": 156001,
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "key": "2dwfy5"
}
match: {
    "path": "/realmUser/new",
    "url": "/realmUser/new",
    "isExact": true,
    "params": {}
}
```

Comment: where did you defined `props`?

Comment: Thank you for answer, did you refer to export interface IRealmUserUpdateProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }> { } ?

Comment: I have tried also not using the props. but in this way nothing happened

Comment: could you add `console.log` here `export const RealmUserUpdate = (props: IRealmUserUpdateProps) => { console.log(props)}` to check what props you are getting

Comment: @Georgy I edit the question with the result of console.log thank you

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like this console log of `location`, not of `props`

Comment: I think that it is the problem, I cant comunicate with reducer

Comment: I guess it would be better if you try to create some example on codesandbox, otherwise I don't have any clue

Comment: thank you for your time, Fortunately I have found the error! :)

Comment: What it was? :)

Comment: The problem was in my Routes, I had import the page as import { RealmUser } ... and not import RealmUser from ... :)